# Converting a "set" into lowercase

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm working on a .bat file that asks for a nickname (but uppercase)

```
set /p nickname="Please enter your uppercase name!:
```

and I wonder if I can make the bat store both original (uppercase) nickname and all lowercase nickname.

So I can do it like

```
%nickname%\files\avatar\1.png
```

or

```
%nickname_lowercase%\files\avatar\1.png
```

I don't want to ask the user for the lowercase nickname, I just want it to convert what user enters to lowercase and store it in a "set" or something.
It's a bit complicated, sorry if I couldn't explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I convert the contents of a variable to lower case?

Use the following batch file:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p nickname="Please enter your uppercase name!:
rem save the name, use "s in case there are space in the name
set "_UpperNick=nickname"
call LoCase nickname
set "_LowerNick=nickname"
echo _UpperNick
echo _LowerNick
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF

:LoCase
:: Subroutine to convert a variable VALUE to all lower case.
:: The argument for this subroutine is the variable NAME.
SET %~1=!%~1:A=a!
SET %~1=!%~1:B=b!
SET %~1=!%~1:C=c!
SET %~1=!%~1:D=d!
SET %~1=!%~1:E=e!
SET %~1=!%~1:F=f!
SET %~1=!%~1:G=g!
SET %~1=!%~1:H=h!
SET %~1=!%~1:I=i!
SET %~1=!%~1:J=j!
SET %~1=!%~1:K=k!
SET %~1=!%~1:L=l!
SET %~1=!%~1:M=m!
SET %~1=!%~1:N=n!
SET %~1=!%~1:O=o!
SET %~1=!%~1:P=p!
SET %~1=!%~1:Q=q!
SET %~1=!%~1:R=r!
SET %~1=!%~1:S=s!
SET %~1=!%~1:T=t!
SET %~1=!%~1:U=u!
SET %~1=!%~1:V=v!
SET %~1=!%~1:W=w!
SET %~1=!%~1:X=x!
SET %~1=!%~1:Y=y!
SET %~1=!%~1:Z=z!
GOTO:EOF
```

Source [Batch files - How To ... Convert Strings To Upper Case Or Lower Case](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php)

Answer (score 2):

For a predictive character set, this substring **`Set !var:A=a!`** works, and only working with **predefined substring** in **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**.

For this type of task, why not get a little help with **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)**, which can make it possible to work with unconventional accents and consonants **è, È, ä, Ä, ñ, Ñ, ç, Ç etc.**

Where the **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** will generate **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code, it will be compiled and executed at run time ....

Which solves possible user inputs, in which the sequence comes with accents and the vowels/consonants are different from the conventional ones **[a-z]** and/or **[A_Z]**

**Obs:** - Also work with ***nicknames with spaces*** and/or with ***compose names***

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

cd /d "%~dp0" && title <nul && title ...\%~dpnx0 /// !time:~0,8! !date!
set "_where=%__appdir__%where.exe" && set "_csc=%windir%\Microsoft.NET"
set "_findstr=%__APPDIR__%\findstr.exe" && del /q /f "%tmp%\ToUpLower.*" 2>nul >nul 

>"%temp%\ToUpLower.cs"^
   ( 
echo= using System; namespace SUQ1522019 ^{class Program ^{static void Main(string[] args^) ^{
echo= if (args.Length==2 ^&^& args[0].ToLower(^)=="-l"^) ^{Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToLower(^)^);^} 
echo= if (args.Length==2 ^&^& args[0].ToLower(^)=="-u"^) ^{Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToUpper(^)^);^}^}^}^}
   ) && set "_arg=/t:exe /out:"%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" "%temp%\ToUpLower.cs" /platform:anycpu "

:loop
if exist "%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" goto :next
for /l %%L in (4 -1 2)do for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('!_where! /r "!_csc!" csc.exe ^|!_findstr! /lic:"\v%%~L\."')do (
   set "_compiller="%%~i" !_arg! /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo" && call !_compiller! && set /p "_nick="Please enter nickname: "
   if not "!_nick!"=="" (goto :next) else cls && goto :loop
  )

:next
for /f tokens^=^*delims^=^"  %%# in ('echo[!_nick!') do for /f tokens^=^*delims^=^" %%U in ('
call "%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" -u "%%#"')do set "_up_case_nick=%%~U" && for /f tokens^=^*delims^=^" %%l in ('
call "%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" -l "%%#"')do set "_low_case_nick=%%~l" ) else goto :loop

echo/ Your input nickname is: !_nick!
echo/   Your input upcase is: !_up_case_nick!
echo/  Your input lowcase is: !_low_case_nick!

echo/ >nul 2>nul copy "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "." 
del /q /f "%tmp%\ToUpLower.*" >nul 2>nul && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Outputs for input == **`To Up Lower`**

  ---

```bat
 Please enter nickname: To Up Lower

Your input nickname is: To Up Lower
  Your input upcase is: TO UP LOWER
 Your input lowcase is: to up lower
```

---

The **`ToUpLower.cs`** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code with no escaping:

---

```bat
 using System; namespace SUQ1522019 {class Program {static void Main(string[] args) {
 if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-l") {Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToLower());} 
 if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-u") {Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToUpper());}}}}
```

---

The **`ToUpLower.cs`** **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code with no escaping and indented:

---

```bat
using System
namespace SUQ1522019 
{
   class Program 
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-l") 
         {
            Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToLower());
         } 

         if (args.Length==2 && args[0].ToLower()=="-u") 
         {
            Console.WriteLine(args[1].ToUpper());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

---

- This **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code was **compiled/tested** on **`csc.exe`** versions:

```bat
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

---

- This is the **command line** used to **compile** the **[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)** code:

  ---

```bat
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe /t:exe /out:"%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "%tmp%\ToUpLower.cs" /platform:anycpu /unsafe+ /w:0 /o /nologo
```

---

- **`ToUpLower.exe` usage**  UPPER to -> lower 


  ---

```bat
ToUpLower.exe -l STRING 

:: if have space, use quote:

ToUpLower.exe -l "THIS STRING" 

:: or ..

ToUpLower.exe -L STRING

:: if have space, use quote:

ToUpLower.exe -L "THIS STRING"
```

---

- **`ToUpLower.exe` usage**  lower to -> UPPER

---

```bat
ToUpLower.exe -u string

:: if have space, use quote:

ToUpLower.exe -u "this string"

:: or ..

ToUpLower.exe -U string

:: if have space, use quote:

ToUpLower.exe -U "this string"
```

---

To keep **`ToUpLower.exe`**, remove **`echo/`** from **`copy`** **command**:

---

```
echo/ >nul 2>nul copy "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "."
```

- This command line will copy **`ToUpLower.exe`** from **`%temp%`** to same the same folder where your bat is running.

  ---

Programming Guide C#:

- **[Args](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments)**
- **[ToLower](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_ToLower)**
- **[ToUpper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_ToUpper)**

---

- **Edit:** This code will compile the C# source code with the first .Net Framework found in this order:

  ---

```bat
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
```

---

- A second option will be to **add/join** the **`ToUpLower.exe`** executable on the **`batch`** file, using **base64** strings and **decoding at run time** .

  What you can do using **`%__APPDIR__%Certutil.exe`**, available on Windows.

**Obs:** - Also work with ***nicknames with spaces*** and/or with ***compose names***

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

cd /d "%~dp0" && title <nul
title ...\%~dpnx0 /// !time:~0,8! !date!
del /q /f "%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" 2>nul >nul

%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe -f -decode "%~dpnx0" "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" 2>nul >nul

:loop
cls & echo/ & set /p "_nick="Please enter nickname: "

if not "!_nick!"==""  (
for /f tokens^=^*delims^=^"  %%# in ('echo[!_nick!') do for /f tokens^=^*delims^=^" %%U in ('
call "%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" -u "%%#"')do set "_up_case_nick=%%~U" && for /f tokens^=^*delims^=^" %%l in ('
call "%temp%\ToUpLower.exe" -l "%%#"')do set "_low_case_nick=%%~l" ) else goto :loop

echo/ Your input nickname is: !_nick!
echo/   Your input upcase is: !_up_case_nick!
echo/  Your input lowcase is: !_low_case_nick!

echo/ 2>nul >nul copy /y "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe" "." 
del /q /f "%tmp%\ToUpLower.*" >nul 2>nul && endlocal & goto :EOF

rem :: Strings Base64 to decode in run time to generate/use the file: "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe"

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5vdCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1vZGUu
DQ0KJAAAAAAAAABQRQAATAEDAPztNl4AAAAAAAAAAOAAAgELAQgAAAYAAAAGAAAAAAAAHiUAAAAgAAAAQAAAAABAAAAg
AAAAAgAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAMAQIUAABAAABAAAAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
ANAkAABLAAAAAEAAAKgCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCAAAEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC50ZXh0AAAAJAUAAAAgAAAA
BgAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAGAucnNyYwAAAKgCAAAAQAAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAABALnJlbG9j
AAAMAAAAAGAAAAACAAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJQAAAAAAAEgAAAACAAUAtCAA
ABwEAAABAAAAAQAABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMwAgBPAAAA
AAAAAAKOaRgzIQIWmm8EAAAKcgEAAHAoBQAACiwNAheabwQAAAooBgAACgKOaRgzIQIWmm8EAAAKcgcAAHAoBQAACiwN
AheabwcAAAooBgAACioeAigIAAAKKgBCU0pCAQABAAAAAAAMAAAAdjIuMC41MDcyNwAAAAAFAGwAAAA0AQAAI34AAKAB
AABgAQAAI1N0cmluZ3MAAAAAAAMAABAAAAAjVVMAEAMAABAAAAAjR1VJRAAAACADAAD8AAAAI0Jsb2IAAAAAAAAAAgAA
AUdVAAAJAAAAAPoBMwAWAAABAAAACAAAAAIAAAACAAAAAQAAAAkAAAADAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAKAAEAAAAAAAYA
OwA0AAYAaQBNAAYAhQBNAAYAtACUAAYA1ACUAAYAAQE0AAYAHAE0AAYARgE2AQAAAAABAAAAAAABAAEAAAAQABgAIAAF
AAEAAQBQIAAAAACRAEIACgABAKsgAAAAAIYYRwAQAAIAAAABAPwAEQBHABQAIQBHABoAKQBHABAAMQAIAR8AMQAQASMA
OQAkASkAMQAuAR8ACQBHABAAQQBHABAAJwBLAC4ALgATADMALgAbADwACAAGAFsABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8gAA
AAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAKwAAAAAAAAAAAAA8TW9kdWxlPgBUb1VwTG93ZXIuZXhlAFByb2dyYW0AU1VRMTUyMjAxOQBt
c2NvcmxpYgBTeXN0ZW0AT2JqZWN0AE1haW4ALmN0b3IAU3lzdGVtLlNlY3VyaXR5LlBlcm1pc3Npb25zAFNlY3VyaXR5
UGVybWlzc2lvbkF0dHJpYnV0ZQBTZWN1cml0eUFjdGlvbgBTeXN0ZW0uUnVudGltZS5Db21waWxlclNlcnZpY2VzAENv
bXBpbGF0aW9uUmVsYXhhdGlvbnNBdHRyaWJ1dGUAUnVudGltZUNvbXBhdGliaWxpdHlBdHRyaWJ1dGUAVG9VcExvd2Vy
AGFyZ3MAU3RyaW5nAFRvTG93ZXIAb3BfRXF1YWxpdHkAQ29uc29sZQBXcml0ZUxpbmUAVG9VcHBlcgBTeXN0ZW0uU2Vj
dXJpdHkAVW52ZXJpZmlhYmxlQ29kZUF0dHJpYnV0ZQAABS0AbAABBS0AdQABAAAA1T5f5CmhU0i1Zns61KGndwAIt3pc
Vhk04IkFAAEBHQ4DIAABBSABARENBCABAQgDIAAOBQACAg4OBAABAQ4EAQAAAAgBAAgAAAAAAB4BAAEAVAIWV3JhcE5v
bkV4Y2VwdGlvblRocm93cwGAni4BgIRTeXN0ZW0uU2VjdXJpdHkuUGVybWlzc2lvbnMuU2VjdXJpdHlQZXJtaXNzaW9u
QXR0cmlidXRlLCBtc2NvcmxpYiwgVmVyc2lvbj0yLjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2Vu
PWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODkVAVQCEFNraXBWZXJpZmljYXRpb24BAPgkAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4lAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJQAAAAAAAAAAX0NvckV4ZU1haW4AbXNjb3JlZS5kbGwAAAAAAP8lACBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAEAAAABgAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAQAAADAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAEgA
AABYQAAATAIAAAAAAAAAAAAATAI0AAAAVgBTAF8AVgBFAFIAUwBJAE8ATgBfAEkATgBGAE8AAAAAAL0E7/4AAAEAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8AAAAAAAAABAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABEAAAAAQBWAGEAcgBGAGkAbABlAEkAbgBmAG8A
AAAAACQABAAAAFQAcgBhAG4AcwBsAGEAdABpAG8AbgAAAAAAAACwBKwBAAABAFMAdAByAGkAbgBnAEYAaQBsAGUASQBu
AGYAbwAAAIgBAAABADAAMAAwADAAMAA0AGIAMAAAACwAAgABAEYAaQBsAGUARABlAHMAYwByAGkAcAB0AGkAbwBuAAAA
AAAgAAAAMAAIAAEARgBpAGwAZQBWAGUAcgBzAGkAbwBuAAAAAAAwAC4AMAAuADAALgAwAAAAPAAOAAEASQBuAHQAZQBy
AG4AYQBsAE4AYQBtAGUAAABUAG8AVQBwAEwAbwB3AGUAcgAuAGUAeABlAAAAKAACAAEATABlAGcAYQBsAEMAbwBwAHkA
cgBpAGcAaAB0AAAAIAAAAEQADgABAE8AcgBpAGcAaQBuAGEAbABGAGkAbABlAG4AYQBtAGUAAABUAG8AVQBwAEwAbwB3
AGUAcgAuAGUAeABlAAAANAAIAAEAUAByAG8AZAB1AGMAdABWAGUAcgBzAGkAbwBuAAAAMAAuADAALgAwAC4AMAAAADgA
CAABAEEAcwBzAGUAbQBiAGwAeQAgAFYAZQByAHMAaQBvAG4AAAAwAC4AMAAuADAALgAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAwAAAAgNQAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA= -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

---

- The commandline used to **decode** the **Base64** to file **`"%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe"`**

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe -f -decode "%~dpnx0" "%tmp%\ToUpLower.exe"  2>nul >nul
```

---

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Convert text to upper case: (char limit 255)

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %i in ('find "" "lower case text" 2^>^&1') do set i=%i& echo !i:~1!
```

Convert to lower case: (char limit 255)

```
type nul > "UPPER CASE"
dir /l /b "UPPER CASE"
```

or

```
md al & cd al
echo:> "SOME LONG FILENAME in here"
dir /l /b
```

To change case of entire file:

```
set case=upper
set file=line.txt

if exist out.txt del out.txt

for %i in (%file%) do set n=%~zi
fsutil file createnew A %n% >nul
fc /b A %file% | more +1 > B

type nul > A
for /f "tokens=3" %i in (B) do (

if %case%==lower (
if 0x%i gtr 0x40 (if 0x%i lss 0x5b (set /a a=0x%i+0x20 >nul) else set /a a=0x%i >nul) else set /a a=0x%i >nul
)
if %case%==upper (
if 0x%i gtr 0x60 (if 0x%i lss 0x7b (set /a a=0x%i-0x20 >nul) else set /a a=0x%i >nul) else set /a a=0x%i >nul
)
cmd /c exit /b !a! & set hex=!=exitcode:~-2!& set /p=!hex! <nul

) >> A

certutil -decodehex A out.txt

del A & del B
```

*Notes:*

`exitcodeASCII` & `forfiles` can achieve the same task and probably faster, with more code to handle TAB, SPACE, CR & LF.

Tested on Win 10 cmd

**Sample output:** (from out.txt)

Original

> In the beginning, there was time. As time spread out from the point of
> emergence, the pressure of the void in the increasing space stretched
> the energy that held the time in zero space, raising the chances of
> energy clumping together as temperatures in the vacuum cooled, giving
> rise to matter in pockets of regions cooler than others.
>
> Some matter & > < became too huge that it began attracting other
> matter around it, thereby raising it's own temperature back up again,
> and eventually cooling off either by sudden supernova or slow pulsar
> and quasar radiation. This heating & cooling eventually stabilised to
> a resonance that beats life in the heart of this universe.

Uppercase

> IN THE BEGINNING, THERE WAS TIME. AS TIME SPREAD OUT FROM THE POINT OF
> EMERGENCE, THE PRESSURE OF THE VOID IN THE INCREASING SPACE STRETCHED
> THE ENERGY THAT HELD THE TIME IN ZERO SPACE, RAISING THE CHANCES OF
> ENERGY CLUMPING TOGETHER AS TEMPERATURES IN THE VACUUM COOLED, GIVING
> RISE TO MATTER IN POCKETS OF REGIONS COOLER THAN OTHERS.
>
> SOME MATTER & > < BECAME TOO HUGE THAT IT BEGAN ATTRACTING OTHER
> MATTER AROUND IT, THEREBY RAISING IT'S OWN TEMPERATURE BACK UP AGAIN,
> AND EVENTUALLY COOLING OFF EITHER BY SUDDEN SUPERNOVA OR SLOW PULSAR
> AND QUASAR RADIATION. THIS HEATING & COOLING EVENTUALLY STABILISED TO
> A RESONANCE THAT BEATS LIFE IN THE HEART OF THIS UNIVERSE.

Lowercase

> in the beginning, there was time. as time spread out from the point of
> emergence, the pressure of the void in the increasing space stretched
> the energy that held the time in zero space, raising the chances of
> energy clumping together as temperatures in the vacuum cooled, giving
> rise to matter in pockets of regions cooler than others.
>
> some matter & > < became too huge that it began attracting other
> matter around it, thereby raising it's own temperature back up again,
> and eventually cooling off either by sudden supernova or slow pulsar
> and quasar radiation. this heating & cooling eventually stabilised to
> a resonance that beats life in the heart of this universe.

copyright ©, all rights reserved 
The supplied code is for stackexchange only, and shall not be published outside of this site.