# Issue with reg add command for automating desktop icon selections

Tags: batch, batch-file, windows-registry, shell-script

I am looking for some help on what is causing my batch file to not execute the following commands. I am trying to change the desktop icons for mass automation for imaging. There is a lot more to the code, but I am going to paste what is relevant to the question. Help me understand why I can run the reg add commands in command prompt and it saves the registry edits but when I run the batch file (WITH ADMINISTRATIVE RIGHTS) the reg edits do not save to registry editor.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
Title Lets making Imaging Policies a bit faster!
OpenFiles > NUL > 2&1

:Menu
echo  =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
echo  !ESC![34mWelcome %username%: %Msg1%!ESC![0m
echo  =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
echo.
echo      Do not close this cmd prompt window if you are running a command.
echo      You need some cmd skill to use this, if you need help just ask.
echo.
echo   1. Change Desktop Icons

Set INPUT= 
Set /P INPUT=Enter a Menu number and press ^< Enter ^> :

If /I '%INPUT%'=='0'  Goto Exit
If /I '%INPUT%'=='1'  Goto DESKTOP_ICON

:DESKTOP_ICON
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu" /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v {59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee} /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu" /v {59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee} /t REG_DWORD /d 0

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E} /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu" /v {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E} /t REG_DWORD /d 0

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu" /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v {59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee} /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu" /v {59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee} /t REG_DWORD /d 0

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E} /t REG_DWORD /d 0
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu" /v {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E} /t REG_DWORD /d 0

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
echo  Please wait 10 seconds to allow the script to run. Do not worry about the background, the explorer is refreshing
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
echo  Thanks for being patient! Now allow everything to reload
start explorer.exe
echo.
echo ^< Press ANY key to return to the Menu ^> & Pause > NUL)
CLS & Goto :Menu
```

Comment: I just didn't test it, but if it was, I would use:  `reg add ... ^{  ... ˆ}` See if it changes some things...

Comment: At least where I will echo `{}`, it was necessary, as in this answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1522019/converting-a-set-into-lowercase/1522183#1522183) 
or try using `red add ... "{ ... } "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bath
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Title <nul & cd /d "%~dp0" & OpenFiles 1>nul 2>&1
Title Lets making Imaging Policies a bit faster!!

set _bar=<nul & for /l %%L in =;(1 1 38);= do set "_bar=!_bar!=+"
set "_Msg1=Variable: %%_Msg1%% // not defined in your question //"

for /f skip^=4 %%b in =;('echo;prompt;$H^|cmd.exe');= do set "_BS=%%~b"
for /f skip^=4 %%e in =;('echo;prompt $E^|cmd.exe');= do set "_$E=%%~e"

set "_KEY=HKCU,HKLM"
set "_NST=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel"
set "_CSM=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu"
set "_REG=20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D,59031a47-3f72-44a7-89c5-5595fe6b30ee,645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E"

:Menu
cls & echo\  !_bar! 
echo\     !_$E![34m    Welcome %username%: %_Msg1%!_$E![0m & echo\  !_bar!
echo\     Do not close this cmd prompt window if you are running a command.
echo\     You need some cmd skill to use this, if you need help just ask. & echo\
echo\  1. Change Desktop Icons & echo\  2. Keep without Changing Icons

Set /p INPUT=<nul & Set /P INPUT=!_BS!  Enter a Menu number and press ^< Enter ^> : || Goto :Menu

echo\"%INPUT%" | findstr ^"1^" >nul && Goto :DESKTOP_ICON || >nul =;(
     echo\"%INPUT%" | findstr ^"2^" && Goto :Exit || Goto :Menu );=

:DESKTOP_ICON
for %%K in =;(!_KEY!);= do for %%r in =;("!_NST!","!_CSM!");= do for %%# in =;(
    !_REG!);= do 1>nul reg add "%%~K\%%~r" /v "{%%~#}" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 2>&1
 
1>nul taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & timeout /t 10 /nobreak | =;( 
     echo\  Please wait 10 seconds to allow the script to run.
     echo\  Do not worry about the background, the explorer is refreshing
    );= && echo\  Thanks for being patient! Now allow everything to reload
    
start "" explorer.exe & echo.
timeout -1  | set /p ".=!_BS!  < Press ANY key to return to the Menu >" & Goto :Menu

:Exit
endlocal
```

---

I assume you are running as ***administrator***, so try using:
`""` in `"{ ... }"`
`/f` in `... /d 0 /f`